# Deployment for PHP and Angular JS Based Web Application

Tags: php, angularjs, web-deployment

Currently I have developed the web application using PHP as backend and Angular JS for Front and I have tested the app by hosting in XAMPP local server, Now I wanted to move it to Real Server Which is the best way . Is there any build tool available for this .

```
Below are the details
Angular JS : 1.2.32
PHP :7.0.22
```

And My Application folder structure as below

```
CSS(Folder) ->Contains CSS 
JS(Folder) -> Contains all the Angular JS related Controllers
IMG(Folder) -> Contains all the images
index.html -> Start Page
configuration file -> Contains credentials info
```

Comment: I strongly recommend doing a Google search for tutorials or advice on this subject

Comment: i think the question if off-topic, there isnt a question about some error on coding. like @Kai says its better googling to find some examples. Also i think if the production server has the same configuration exept the enviroment variables, could work for you.